# Are sin and cos the only continuous and infinitely differentiable periodic functions we have?

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

Sin and cos are everywhere continuous and infinitely differentiable.  Those are nice properties to have.  They come from the unit circle.

It seems there's *no other* periodic function that is also smooth and continuous.  The only other even *periodic* functions (not smooth or continuous) I have seen are:

- Square wave
- Triangle wave
- Sawtooth wave

Are there any other well-known periodic functions?

Comment: There are plenty. Just construct a nice $f$ on $[a,b]$ to have the same values and same derivatives at $x=a$ and $x=b$. Then ``extend'' $f$ to all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Note that smoothness implies continuity. How are your three examples smooth? Or do you mean piecewise smooth?

Comment: @wildildildlife Sorry, I meant square, tri, sawtooth are the only other common _periodic_ functions I have seen.

Comment: $5\sin(x) + 7\cos(2x)$ is neither $\sin$ nor $\cos$.

Comment: or something like $\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}$...

Comment: Constant functions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Are there any other well-known periodic functions?"

In one sense, the answer is "no".  Every reasonable periodic complex-valued function $f$ of a real variable can be represented as an infinite linear combination of sines and cosines with periods equal the period $\tau$ of $f$, or equal to $\tau/2$ or to $\tau/3$, etc.  See [Fourier series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series).

There are also doubly periodic functions of a complex variable, called [elliptic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_function).  If one restricts one of these to the real axis, one can find a Fourier series, but one doesn't do such restrictions, as far as I know, in studying these functions.  See [Weierstrass's elliptic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions) and [Jacobi elliptic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_elliptic_functions).

Comment: ....but I haven't said what "reasonable" means nor mentioned the various senses in which a Fourier series might or might not converge.

Comment: On the other hand, the elliptic functions are (necessarily!) meromorphic, while the exponential and trigonometric functions are periodic and holomorphic. One could think of the usual singly-periodic functions as "degenerate" doubly-periodic functions with one infinite period...

Answer (score 7):

There are some unreasonable ones that are periodic.

$$f(x) =\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^{n}e^{-(x-n)^2}$$

is periodic with period 2. Looks like cosine but is not.

Comment: I'm not sure this one is "unreasonable". Doesn't it have a convergent Fourier series?

Answer (score 3):

This is an extension of David Mitra answer.

Pick any functions which is smooth on an open interval containing $[0,1]$.

Define $g: [0,1] \rightarrow R$ by $g(x)=x^2(1-x)^2f(x)$. Then $g(0)=g'(0)=g(1)=g'(1)=0$.

You can now prove that $h: R \rightarrow R$ defined by

$$h(x) = g( \{ x \}) \,,$$

where $\{ x \}$ represents the fractional part of $x$ is smooth periodic with period 1...

Comment: [Funnily enough... I had talked about something similar!](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63456/63463#63463)

Comment: That's not smooth! For $f(x)=1$, the third derivative jumps at every integer. However, you could make $g(x)=e^{\left(\frac{-1}{x(1-x)}\right)}f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not.

For example, $\sin_{[n]}(x)$ as shown in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root is in fact a smooth periodic function of period $2\pi$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{R}^+$ .