# periodic holomorphic function other than the exponent function

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there a function $f$, in the complex plane, such that $f(z)$ is both analytic and periodic and doesn't involve $e^z$ in it? I've tried:

$g\big(\mbox{Real}(z)\big) \Big( \cos(Im(z))+i \sin(\mbox{Im}(z)) \Big)$

For function of real number $g$, but haven't been able to find an appropriate $g$.

Comment: Any constant function is both holomorphic and periodic... do you mean for your question to exclude constant functions?

Comment: @AWertheim : Maybe those have $e^z$ in them: $c(e^z)^0$.

Comment: "Does not involve" is a bit vague.  For example, every periodic entire function $f$ with period $2\pi i$ can be written as $f(z) = g(e^z)$ where $g$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$.  Does this involve $e^z$?

Comment: @MichaelHardy, fair enough, though I figured that was a trivial "inclusion"... if there is a $g(z)$ satisfying his query, then it could be immediately be disqualified by noting that $g(z) = g(z)(e^{z})^{0}$.

Comment: Role reversal: Last time someone asked this question, I'm the one who wrote "In one sense, the answer is 'no'." and pointed out Fourier series, and someone else mentioned $\sum_n\exp(-(x-n)^2)$. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81411/are-sin-and-cos-the-only-continuous-and-infinitely-differentiable-periodic-funct

Comment: "Does not involve exp" meaning that we can express this function without using the exponent function at all.

Answer (score 2):

In a certain sense there is none. Assume that $f$ is analytic and $2\pi$-periodic (the period doesn't really matter, it's just to simplify the notation), defined on some horizontal strip $|\operatorname{Im} z| < a$.  Then $f$ can be written as a Fourier series
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{inz}
$$
with uniform convergence on $|\operatorname{Im} z| \le b$ for every $b < a$.

Comment: Thanks,
When we consider an expression such as $e^z$ the problem is that $|e^z|$ may grow large. As a result it may be hard to estimate the integral of a function that involves $e^z$ on ,say, a circular domain with sufficiently large radius.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was that Jacobi's and Weierstrass' elliptic functions are doubly periodic, but then I thought you might object to their poles.

How about this:
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \exp\left(-(z-n)^2\right).
$$
That has $\exp((z-n)^2)$ rather than $\exp((z-\text{whatever})^1)$.