# Are there oscillating functions that don't reduce to trigonometric functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am wondering whether there exists a class of oscillating functions that are distinct from trigonometric functions.  The only oscillating functions I could think of are of the $e^{ix}$ and $(-1)^x$ varieties, but these are easily expressed as trigonometric functions (or sums thereof).  I'm looking for functions that cannot be expressed as finite sums of trigonometric functions (but functions that are not themselves finite sums either).

I'm not sure how best to phrase this, but I'm looking for non-trivial answers to this.  Its trivial to find a function that has the same value at two distinct x-values and tile it infinitely.  I'm looking for something that can be expressed in a simpler way than an infinite piece-wise function.

Comment: Do you allow infinite sums of trigonometric functions? Are you familiar with Fourier series? What about a square wave, or sawtooth wave?

Comment: What do you mean by "oscillating"? Fourier analysis shows that every "nice" _periodic_ function can be written as an (infinite) sum of trigonometric functions.

Comment: @Potato Yes, I am familiar.  I should've specified; something that cannot be written as a finite sum of trigonometric functions.  Updating the question..

Comment: The Stone-Weierstrass theorem ensures that the set of trigonometric polynomials are dense in the set of continuous functions in the uniform norm, which basically means that for every continuous function and a chosen very small error, you can find a sum of trigonometric terms which approximates that function with that error everywhere.

Comment: @AaronDufour Functions that can be written as finite sums of trigonometric functions have a finite Fourier series - finding the fourier series "exposes" if it can be written as a finite sum of trig functions. So a sawtooth wave will never be able to be written as a finite sum of trig functions. Another way to see that is to note that any finite sum of trig functions is smooth while a sawtooth has non-differentiable points.

Comment: Do you think something like $x\mapsto\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-n}\sin(nx)$ is "simpler" than a definition by cases?

Comment: Does $e^{\sin x}$ qualify as "simple"?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes - by simple, I want to avoid infinite sums or piecewise functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph of [$f(x) = x \pmod n$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) for any integer $n$ is periodic. In case you are not familiar with modular arithmetic, $f(x)$ is the remainder of $x$ after division by $n$. As an example, here is $f(x) = x \pmod 5$, courtesy of WolframAlpha:

[image: x mod 5]

Comment: This is what I was looking for!  Something that I'm familiar with but completely blanked on.  Thanks

Comment: This has an infinite Fourier expansion due to having only one discontinuity per cycle.

Answer (score 3):

What about a "saw" function, with graph something like:

```
   .     .     .
  . .   . .   . .
 .   . .   . .
.     .     .
```

and then extended in the obvious way? But of course this can be represented via 
**infinite** sums of trigonometric functions ... that is called Fourier theory

A formula for the above saw function might be
$$
    f(x) = \begin{cases} x,   & \text{if $0\le x \le 1$} \\
                         2-x, & \text{if $1 \le x \le 2$}  \end{cases}
$$
and then extended periodically.

Comment: How can this be expressed algebraically?

Comment: updated the answer to answer that.

Comment: You may want to adjust the intervals so that $f(1)$ results in 1 value only.

Comment: Like in the other answer, I'm looking for a non-trivial expression.  In looking for something periodic, its trivial to tile a function over a short range infinitely.  Can this be expressed more simply?  (Something to do with floor/ceiling functions, perhaps?)

Comment: @AaronDufour Periodic *means* tile a function infinitely. Trigonometric functions don't appear to be defined in this way, but the fact that they discard multiples of $2\pi$ is equivalent to just defining it on $[0, 2\pi]$ and then tiling.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = e^{-1/x(x-1)}$ for $0<x<1$ and $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Extend periodically to all of $\mathbb R$.

The result is $\mathcal C^\infty$ and (by construction) periodic, but it is not a finite sum of trigonometric functions. Such a sum must be analytic but our $f$ is not analytic at the integers.

Comment: Can this be expressed algebraically?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. You can certainly frame the _result_ with words that belong to algebra (the set of horizontally scaled trigonometric functions does not algebraically span the vector space of periodic functions), but particularly enlightening it ain't.

Comment: The obvious way to express what you've written is as an infinite piecewise function.  Can it be expressed more simply than that?

Comment: My point is that you can do this for any function that has the same value at two different x values, by tiling them infinitely.  Can this one be represented in a simpler way than that?

Comment: Generally periodic extension for "any function that has the same value at two different $x$ values" will not produce a $\mathcal C^\infty$ result.

Comment: I had not heard of $C^\infty$; its an interesting concept.  However, I don't care whether the function is $C^\infty$.  I updated my question to be more specific about what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly what comes to mind is [BESSEL FUNCTIONS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), of which there are many kinds. Note that $$ f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}  $$ extends with $f(0) = 1$ to an function that oscillates but cannot be written as a sum of sines and cosines.

If you are insisting on genuinely **periodic** functions, you are out of luck, as such will have Fourier series if piecewise continuous.

On the other hand, here is one that has roots at constant intervals and constant amplitude, 
$$   g(x) = \left( 2 + \cos \left( \frac{8 x^2}{\pi} \right) \; \right) \; \sin x        $$ 
but has no Fourier series. Would I lie?

Answer (score 1):

To extend Austin's answer: as I have noted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/63463), one could use the sawtooth function $x\bmod 1$ to represent any periodic function on the real line, if you know the "repeating unit". To summarize the point of that answer: if you want your function to be a repeated version of the function $f(x)$ over the interval $[a,b]$, and $f(a)=f(b)$, then $f\left(x\bmod(b-a)\right)$ is the function you want. One can then choose an $f$ that involves no trigonometric functions whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

If you extend the (-1)^x , where x is an unknown function,to coin-flips, or random {-1,1}.The series, S=∑{-1,1} can be a non-symmetric random walk with zeros proportional to the geometric mean of #+1's and #-1's. There are 2^n of these "functions". It may be impossible to express them algebraically or as trigonometric functions. They could be a "function" if stored on a computer.( I use 1e6 digits of pi as a source.)